# Wordpress ignores excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

Using the below I am able to populate a list and the text from my posts into my Sidebar in Wordpress.

I have placed the `<!--more-->` tag into my post but it seems to get ignored using the below script.

Could someone assist please

**PHP in Wordpress**

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=2' ); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <p><?php the_content('<span class="readmore strong">'.__('Read more').'</span>'); ?></p>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get only one post back the `<!--more-->` will be ignored, see [the_excerpt() vs. the_content()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)

> Sometimes, it is more meaningful to use only the `the_content()`
>   function which will decide what to display according to whether the
>   `<!--more-->` quicktag was used. The `<!--more-->` quicktag splits a post
>   into two parts; only the content before the tag should be displayed in
>   listing. Remember that `<!--more-->` is (of course) ignored when showing
>   a single post.

Just try to use `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`.

**Update:**
Like I said in the comments and [Donald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1152045/donald) got helped from the [WordPress Support](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-more-tag-work-on-pages#post-628393), the solution seems to be to override the global `$more` like [WordPress Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Overriding_Archive.2FSingle_Page_Behavior):

```
<?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>
```

In the context of this question:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=2' ); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
    <?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <p><?php the_content('<span class="readmore strong">'.__('Read more').'</span>'); ?></p>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

should do it.

Comment: I have 2 posts and the_content and excerpt are both ignorign the `<!--more-->` tag

Comment: Hmm could you try to add `<?php global $more;
$more = 0; ?>` below your while loop? And what wordpress version do you use? `showposts=2`seems long be gone. (but seems not to be the issue here ;) )

Answer (score 0):

[Answer from Wordpress Support](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-more-tag-work-on-pages#post-628393)

**functions.php**

```
function force_more() {
    global $more;
    $more = 0;
}
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<?php
  force_more();
  query_posts('category_name=mycategory&showposts=5');
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```